# How to get posts from google+ stream

Tags: google-plus

I need to take google+ posts from stream and publish them on my site. I know that google doesn't have api to do that. But some services like suck http://www.friendsplus.me/ can do that. Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 6):

First, you should go to google apis and enable Google Plus services. Here it comes;

1. Go to [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).
2. Select Services
3. Enable Google+ API services.
4. Select API Access
5. Simple API Access > grab your API Key.

And you can use following code for read stream posts;

```
<?php

$google_plus_id = '106670447018211124292';
$appKey = 'app_key_here';
$streams = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/' . $google_plus_id . '/activities/public?key='. $appKey));

foreach ($streams->items as $item) {
  echo $item->title .
    date('F jS Y @ H:i:s',strtotime($item->published)) .
    $item->object->content .
    '<br />';
}
```

You can also test this code's job on google api console.

**1.)** Go to [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) and select Google+ API

**2.)** Select **APIs** menu on left menu

**3.)** Click on **public.activities.list** on that page

[image]

**4.)** Enter your **profile id** in **userId** section and type "public" on **collection** section then click **Execute**. You can see below;

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your exact needs, the Google+ API documented at https://developers.google.com/+/api/ may do what you need. It can show you the public posts from a specific user. You can also see some sample code to illustrate this at https://bakingdisasters.com/.

What it can't do, however, is show you the private posts from that user that are permitted to you, or show you all of the posts (public or private) that you may have seen.